# What does the line "fm2.fm1 = this;" actually do?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my current code:

I have this line in my code because someone said to put it in. It works and I'm not looking to remove it, I'd just like to know what it does. I've tried Google'ing it but I don't even know what to search.

```
Form2 fm2 = new Form2(); 
fm2.productNameTextBox.Text = myBasket[i].ProductName; 
fm2.numQTY.Value = myBasket[i].Quantity; 
fm2.latestPriceTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(myBasket[i].LatestPrice); 

fm2.fm1 = this;

fm2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: *I have this line in my code because someone said to put it in.* So why don't you ask them?

Comment: Why don't you debug your code?

Comment: @Jon because they went to sleep at the moment.

Comment: Have you gone through the code of `fm2` to see what kind of variable is `fm1`?

Comment: @Jon I can't remember who suggested it or find where I asked about it

Comment: liam, Daniel suggested it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792102/i-know-how-to-send-information-from-form1-to-form2-but-how-do-i-edit-it-and-sen), (FYI I still prefer my answer there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> fm2.fm1 = this;

This statement, the current `form` object is assigned to `fm2` object's property `fm1`, `this` represents the current object of class, as current classs is form then this presents current `form` object.

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class. Static
>   member functions do not have a this pointer. The this keyword can be
>   used to access members from within constructors, instance methods, and
>   instance accessors, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @Liam: In other worlds - you give possibility for form2 make changes to form1. Of course, it depends of your code. Btw, strange to ask how works code, which is written by you :-)

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a refference to the instance of class you're currently in. If you use it in `Form2` class, it will reffer to the currently used instance of `Form2`. When you use

```
fm2.fm1 = this;
```

in `Form2` class, you assign the current form to the `Form2` object named `fm1` in the declaration of 'fm2'.